# SQLIte database not able to delete entries

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a SQLdatabase and I want to delete entries that are displayed in a list view using a button that is next to each entry on the list view. But currently it is not letting me delete.

This problem is located in the `selectionargs` variable as shown below. If I put a number e.g. 1, into the `selectionargs` manually it will work, but I have been trying to do it through the a variable that represents each entry. This does not result in an error but just goes straight to the toast message cannot delete. ac.ID refers to the adapter class and the ID of the list item entries.

Bookmark class:

```
public class Bookmark extends AppCompatActivity {

myAdapter myAdapter;
DBManager db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bookmark);
    db = new DBManager(this);

    onLoadAttraction();
   // onLoadTransport();


}

public void onLoadAttraction() {
    ArrayList<Adapter> listData = new ArrayList<Adapter>();
    listData.clear();
    Cursor cursor = db.Query("BookmarkAttraction",null, null, null, DBManager.ColId);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            listData.add(new Adapter(
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.ColType))
                    , cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.ColName))
                    , cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.ColLocation))
                    , cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.ColOpening))
                    , cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.ColClosing))
                    , cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.ColNearbyStop))
            ,null,null,null, null, null));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    myAdapter = new myAdapter(listData);
    ListView ls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ls.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}

public void onLoadTransport(){
    ArrayList<Adapter> listData = new ArrayList<Adapter>();
    listData.clear();
    Cursor cursor = db.Query("BookmarkTransport",null, null, null, DBManager.ColId);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            listData.add(new Adapter(
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.ColType))
                    , cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.ColName))
                    , cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.ColLocation))
                    , null
                    , null
                    , null
                    ,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.ColTime))
                    ,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.ColNextStop))
                    , cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.ColPhoneNumber))
                    ,null,null));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    myAdapter = new myAdapter(listData);
    ListView ls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ls.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}

  class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<Adapter> listItem;
    Adapter ac;
    public myAdapter(ArrayList<Adapter> listItem) {
        this.listItem = listItem;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater myInflator = getLayoutInflater();
        final View myView = myInflator.inflate(R.layout.list_bookmark, null);

       ac = listItem.get(position);


        TextView Type = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.BMType);
        Type.setText(ac.Type);

        TextView Name = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.BMName);
        Name.setText(ac.Name);

        TextView Location = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.BMLocation);
        Location.setText(ac.Location);

        TextView Opening = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.BMOpen);
        Opening.setText(ac.Opening);


        TextView Closing = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.BMClose);


            Closing.setText(ac.Closing);


        TextView NearbyStop1 = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.BMNearbyStop);

            NearbyStop1.setText(ac.NearbyStop);


        Button buttonDelete = (Button)myView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
        buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String[] selectionArgs = {ac.ID};
                int count = db.Delete("BookmarkAttraction","ID=? ",selectionArgs);
                if (count > 0) {
                    onLoadAttraction();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cannnot delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });



        return myView;
    }
}
}
```

DBManager class:

```
 public class DBManager  {

private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;
static final String ColId = "ID";
static final String DBName = "InternalDB";
static final String TableName = "BookmarkAttraction";
static final String TableName2 = "BookmarkTransport";
static final String TableName3 = "Itinerary";
static final String ColItineraryName = "ItineraryName";
static final String ColDate = "Date";
static final String ColType = "Type";
static final String ColName = "Name";
static final String ColLocation = "Location";
static final String ColOpening = "OpeningTime";
static final String ColClosing = "ClosingTime";
static final String ColNearbyStop = "NerbyStop1";


static final String ColTime = "Time";
static final String ColNextStop = "NextStop";
static final String ColPhoneNumber = "PhoneNumber";

static final int DBVersion = 1;

static final String CreateTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TableName + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + ColType+ " TEXT," +
        ColName+ " TEXT," + ColLocation+ " TEXT," + ColOpening+ " TEXT," +ColClosing+ " TEXT," + ColNearbyStop+ " TEXT);";

static  final String CreateTabe2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +TableName2 + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + ColType + " TEXT,"
        + ColName + " TEXT,"
        + ColLocation + " TEXT,"
        + ColTime+ " TEXT,"
        + ColNextStop + " TEXT,"
        + ColPhoneNumber + " TEXT);";

static final String CreateTable3 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TableName3 + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + ColItineraryName + " TEXT,"
        + ColDate + " TEXT," + ColName + " TEXT," + ColLocation + " TEXT," + ColTime + " TEXT);";


static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    Context context;

    DBHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DBName, null, DBVersion);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Toast.makeText(context,DBName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.execSQL(CreateTable);
        Toast.makeText(context,"Table is created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.execSQL(CreateTabe2);
        Toast.makeText(context,"Transport table created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.execSQL(CreateTable3);
        Toast.makeText(context,"Itin table created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TableName);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TableName2);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TableName3);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}


public DBManager(Context context){
    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(context);
    sqlDB = db.getWritableDatabase();
}

public long Insert(String tablename,ContentValues values){
    long ID =  sqlDB.insert(tablename,"",values);
    return ID;
}

public Cursor Query(String tablename, String [] projection, String selection, String [] selectionArgs, String sortOrder){
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    qb.setTables(tablename);
    Cursor cursor = qb.query(sqlDB,projection, selection, selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
    return cursor;
}

public int Delete(String tablename,String selection, String[] selectionArgs){
    int count = sqlDB.delete(tablename,selection,selectionArgs);
    return count;
}
```

}

Adapter class:

```
 public class Adapter {

public String ID;
public String Type;
public String Name;
public String Location;
public String Opening;
public String Closing;
public String NearbyStop;
public String Time;
public String NextStop;
public String PhoneNumber;
public String Latitude;
public String Longitude;

public Adapter(String type, String name, String location, String opening, String closing,
               String nearbyStop, String time, String nextStop, String phoneNumber, String Latitude,
               String Longitude) {
    this.Type = type;
    this.Name = name;
    this.Location = location;
    this.Opening = opening;
    this.Closing = closing;
    this.NearbyStop = nearbyStop;
    this.Time = time;
    this.NextStop = nextStop;
    this.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.Latitude = Latitude;
    this.Longitude = Longitude;
}
}
```

The code for the delete button is in my bookmark class with the DBManager holding the actual delete code. If anyone can help with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should seriously consider reading about [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `ac` field of your `myAdapter` class, and use it as a method variable inside the `getView` method.

Then use the `ListView.setOnItemClickListener` method to add an on click listener with positional awareness. (do this only once after you set the adapter) This way you can do `listItem.get(position)` to get the item in that position.